# How can I sort a SOLR search on a Child Field

Tags: sorting, search, solr

I am currently trying to sort a SOLR search based on a numeric value in a child document field.
I have recently learned that SOLR 6.6 has added support for this via a function query called childfield().

Can anyone please provide me an example of how to use this function properly? The documentation seems to be lacking and I keep getting an error that a sort order cannot be determined.
Preferably an explanation/example of the $bjq parameter usage would help also.